# how set nested node (Firebase, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nested, firebase

I want to store a nested node like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
            ref.child("clubs").set(
{
"03": { 
    "competities": 
        "102": { "aantalteams": 2 }
    } 
} );
        </script>   
    </head>
</html>
```

This gives me an 'unexpected token'-error on the line where I add competition id "102". Is it not possible to set a nested node at once in Firebase? Or how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

```
"competities": 
    "102": { "aantalteams": 2 }
```

Note that we have `"competities": "102":` which doesn't really make sense.   (Or maybe automatic semicolon insertion takes place here, which would only make things worse.)

Maybe you meant:

```
"competities": {
    "102": { "aantalteams": 2 }
}
```

Comment: you're right i forgot those brackets